# Setting the table name in telegraf mqtt_consumer plugin

Tags: telegraf, questdb

I am using telegraf to write mqtt messages to questdb. Currently, all my mqtt messages are written into the table "mqtt_consumer" by default. How can I change the name, where the mqtt_consumer is writing the data into the db?

```
[inputs.mqtt_consumer.tags]
destinationdb = "mqtt_data"
```

That doesn't work. I cant find an option for that. It could be that the table name needs to be set in the output plugin but I can't find any option for that. This is my output plugin:

```
[[outputs.socket_writer]]
adress = "tcp://localhost:9000"
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe questdb uses the metric name to determine what table it writes to. The metric name is determined by the input name in most cases.

You can rename a metric via:

```
[[processors.rename]]
  [[processors.rename.replace]]
    measurement = "mqtt_consumer"
    dest = "mqtt_data"
```

Edit:

I forgot about the `name_override` option. You can use that to change the name of the measurement directly. See it listed in the [configuration options docs](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/blob/97826bdc73252c232924fc2db013b00301259e0a/docs/CONFIGURATION.md#input-plugins). You could set this for every mqtt_consumer input plugin to get distinct measurement names.

Comment: Would it be possible to have multiple mqtt inputs that write all in differend tables?

Comment: I've updated my comment with the use of the `name_override` option. Give that a shot!